# How to add html attributes without a value to a form in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, parsley.js

If I have this form:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
  First name: <%=  f.text_field :first_name %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

how do I add an html attribute to both `form_for` and `text_field` without assigning a value?

A) `form_for` - I want to add the attribute `data-parsley-validate` here, but the best one I came up with is:

```
<%= form_for @person, html: {'data-parsley-validate' => ''}  %>
```

However this produces `data-parsley-validate=''`. How do I get rid of the `=''`?

B) `text_field`. I want to make the first name field required. I could write:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, required: ''  %>
```

but this produces `required="required"` and not just `required`. While in the case of `required` this is ok, there might be other cases (such as `data-parsley-no-focus`), where I just need the attribute with no value.

How do I do that?

Comment: Don't you think `data-parsley-validate` should have a value like true or false?

Comment: No, see [the documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-installation-basic).

Comment: I'm seeing this on https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads `data-turbolinks-permanent` which in the docs has no `=""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, HTML5 spec says that these attributes are equivalent:

```
<input disabled>
<input disabled="">
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty

> Note that empty attribute syntax is exactly equivalent to specifying the empty string as the value for the attribute, as in the following example.

```
<input disabled="">
```

Comment: So the answer is "you can't"?